# How to know why a record is Dirty in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

is there a way to know why a record is in a dirty state in ember data, I mean what are the attributes and relations that has changed.

I'm having isDirty = true after calling a findAll and I want to debug why this happens.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which version of ember-data you're using (and, now, what you're using as an adapter) this could be different. The behavior [changed in version 9](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#removal-of-dirty-factors). Before then, you could say `record.isDirtyBecause('belongsTo')` and if the record had been marked dirty because the `belongsTo` relationship had changed, it would return `true`. Now, due to some shifts in the responsibilities between Stores and Adapters, it's up to the Adapter to handle this.

> If you still need this information in your adapter, it will be your responsibility to do any bookkeeping in the `dirtyRecordsForAttributeChange` hook [described above](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#adapter-specified-record-dirtying).

Answer (score 7):

As of Ember-Data beta 6 or earlier, there is a `changedAttributes()` function that returns a hash of the attributes that are changed, and their initial/current values. See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/working-with-records/

For example:

```
person.changedAttributes(); //=> { isAdmin: [false, true] }
```

Note that `changedAttributes()` is not a property that you can observe; however, if you needed to do so, you could observe all the properties that might change on the model, and then check `changedAttributes()` inside your computed property/observes function.

For (contrived) example:

```
checkAttributes: (->
  changed = @get('model').changedAttributes()
  if changed['name'] && Object.keys(changed).length == 1
    # Do something if name is the only changed attribute
).property('name', 'alias', 'description')
```